# negated equal vs. not equal

Tags: coding-style

Lately, I've been reading some code that has

```
 if (! (a == b) )
```

instead of

```
 if ( a != b )
```

in some places.

Obviously these are logically equivalent, but I'm wondering if there is any particular reason to use one over the other.

Are there certain circumstances where one is preferable, or is it all just a matter of personal style?

Comment: The first thing I think of when I see this, is either something was deleted from the expression, or the programmer who wrote this came from another language and is new to this one.

Comment: @John MacIntyre - I get the impression that it was the first case.  I.e., he was first checking for equality, then decided to switch his if block with his else block.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I really prefer

```
if ( a != b )
```

simply because you are supposed to **read less** and you understand more quickly the message the programmer wanted to transmit.

**Remember programmers spend more time *reading* code than writing it, so the more you can do to make code more understandable, the better.**

Answer (score 9):

Mostly this is a matter of style (and my preference is for 'a != b'), but there could be an actual difference in operation if a is an object of a class that doesn't have either an operator== or an operator!=.

Comment: You're right.  Depending on language, there could be a difference in how the two evaluate (or if they even compile).

Answer (score 6):

I would avoid

```
if (! (a == b) )
```

since it involves two operations, where there is one operator

```
if ( a != b )
```

that does the exact same thing.  The second is also more readable (if only slightly).

The really big problem I have with

```
if (! (a == b) )
```

is that it made me stop and think "what the heck?"  Good code shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, languages with operator overloading often don't enforce a != for every ==. In this case, !( a == b ) is essential, as a != b is undefined. Furthermore, it *may* make sense in context to use !( a == b ). While the shorter form is preferred for the reasons given elsewhere in this question, the lengthier form can be more descriptive in certain problem sets.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be as simple as possible, ie less statements is better thus the a!=b is 3 constructs as opposed to ! (a=b) which is 4.

Comment: Also, a!=b could never be mistyped into an assignment statement :-}

Answer (score 1):

Any half-way decent compiler will put out the same code (unless == and != have been overloaded, as mentioned elsewhere) so optimization questions are irrelevant.

I don't think I've ever seen "if(!(a==b))" outside of a bigger conditional where it is clearer to not use DeMorgan's theorem, but I guess I could see it as a way of emphasizing that the two values really should be identical and there's something deeply wrong if they're not.  However a honking big "throw OmgICantBelieveThisHappenedException()" on the next line would be even clearer. :-)

Other than these two situations I have to agree with the "use !=" camp since it's clearer when you skim the code.  The '!' can be easily overlooked, especially with some formatting conventions.

Answer (score -5):

This is the DeMorgan theorem. (Augustus De Morgan - Mathematician)

Go for if(a != b)

Comment: You did not answer the question, thus the down vote. Mathematics was never the issue.

Comment: Ive answered this "In computing just choose the more readable or more performing."ut I think this answer isnt just enough. Sorry